# Consumo de Servicio web SOAP con certificados

Tags: c#, soap, web

Debo realizar una aplicativa en `C#` donde pueda consumir un servicio web de un Banco, utilizando certificados:
Estos son los protocolos de transporte, mensajería y el manejo de la seguridad en los mensajes:

Protocolo Transporte: **HTTPS** en doble vía
Protocolo de Mensajería: **SOAP**
Envío de los archivos: Utilizar **Base 64** para codificar los archivos que vienen embebidos en los mensajes **SOAP**
Seguridad de los mensajes: **WS-Security** (firma-cifrado)

Inicialmente realice un proyecto en soapUI-3.6.1, en este proyecto puede configurar los certificados del banco y de la empresa y logre hacer exitosamente las pruebas.

El problema que tengo es al construir la aplicación en C#, no tengo conocimiento de cómo agregar al mensaje de envió los certificados.

Comment: Puedes usar X.509 aqui mas info https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms729856(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: o https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229744(v=vs.110).aspx